# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (NodeJs, Webdriverio, Selenium)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, chai, webdriver-io

I'm attempting to validate the header (Text) of a given web page when making a successful submission.

My command:

```
async confirmSuccessfulSubmission() {
    return $("#contact_reply h1").getText().then((value) => {
        //incorrect text should be:Thank You for your Message!
        expect(value.to.equal("Thank You for your Message!2")); 
    });
}
```

Exception:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

The correct heading is: Thank You for your Message! therefore if the heading is: Thank You for your Message!2 the test should fail (Chai assertion).

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async confirmSuccessfulSubmission() {
  try{
    let value = await $("#contact_reply h1").getText()
    if(value)
       return expect(value).to.equal("Thank You for your Message!2"); 
    return null
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

catch the exception so you could see what's wrong there

Comment: hi @kiarashws thanks for the comment, it seems im still seeing an exception, would you know the code required to catch the exception? [0-0] (node:4108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

Comment: thanks @kiarashws ,  [0-0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined
    at ContactUs_Page.confirmSuccessfulSubmission (C:\Users\GBruno\Desktop\webdriverioFramework\pageObjects\ContactUs_Page.js:51:32)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
[0-0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined
    at ContactUs_Page.confirmSuccessfulSubmission (C:\Users\GBruno\Desktop\webdriverioFramework\pageObjects\ContactUs_Page.js:51:32)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: im trying to implement something like the following: https://webdriver.io/docs/api.html#examples, appreciate your help

Comment: seems im seeing: [0-0] TypeError: value.toEqual is not a function, currently im using chai assertions: https://www.chaijs.com/

Comment: thanks again, Im guessing i would need to make the assertion fail within the catch block?

Comment: Yes, but you can now remove `try/catch` since we discovered what exception was occurring.